# how to resolve url parameters in spring boot controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

--this is my url

```
http://localhost:8080/estates?pageCount=3&pageIndex=2&multiSelector={roomCountRanges:[{from:3,to:3},{from:4,to:4}]}
```

--here is my controller code:
[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnbFC.png)

**--error I am seeing **

```
 Field error in object 'myModel' on field 'multiSelector': rejected value [{roomCountRanges:[{from:3,to:3},{from:4,to:4}]}];
        codes [typeMismatch.myModel.multiSelector,typeMismatch.multiSelector,typeMismatch.com.centanet.service.model.MultiSelector,typeMismatch];
        arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myModel.multiSelector,multiSelector];
        arguments []; default message [multiSelector]];
        default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.centanet.service.model.MultiSelector' for property 'multiSelector';
        nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.centanet.service.model.MultiSelector' for property 'multiSelector': no matching editors or conversion strategy found],
```

any ideas?
many thanks

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnbFC.png):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Your url you are passing Request Params as all properties but Model is expecting body as like below: so create a Model class, set all values and then call controller with passing model class.

```
{
  "pageCount": 3,
  "pageIndex": 2,
  "multiSelector": {
    "roomCountRanges": [
      {
        "from": 3,
        "to": 3
      },
      {
        "from": 4,
        "to": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pass multiSelector as request body, you may want to read it as string in controller and then use `Gson` or `Jackson` to convert it to java object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
gson.fromJson(multiSelector, MultiSelector.class);
```

However, I would pass JSON as request body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like below:

@PostMapping
public void test(@RequestBody MyModel model) {

}

Dont pass the multiSelector as URL parameter, instead send this json via Request body.